# Speed up query for Autocomplete inputbox

Tags: php, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an AutoComplete for my search box.

I have a database with a table of books, so when a user starts typing in the search box, i want to be able to show them a suggestion box with the first 6 titles that match the words it's being typed.

I used Ajax to query a PHP that have the following code:

```
    $terms           = explode( " ", $data->word );
    $terminos        = '';
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( $term == '' || $term == ' ' || strlen($term)==0 ) continue;
        if ( $terminos != '' ) $terminos .= " AND title LIKE '%$term%' ";
        else $terminos .= " title LIKE '%$term%' ";
    }
    $pdo = MySQLUtil::getConnection();
    $query = "SELECT title
                FROM books
                WHERE :terminos
                LIMIT 6";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':terminos',   $terminos,      PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

This solution is very slow and need to know how could I speed up the query.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many records are in the table? What kind of indexes are set up on the table?

Comment: The Table has more than 700.000 records, and it has fulltext indexes for 'title' and 'description' fields

Comment: Does a bind argument of `:terminus` where `$terminus` is a full where clause actually work with bindParam? That rather contradicts what I understand bind params to actually do?

Comment: Have you thought about using [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)?